# Let in an environment steady current exist ; Then we have

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Let in an environment **steady current** exist ; Then we have 
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r})=0$$
And let the environment be **ohmic** ; So we have 
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \sigma(\vec{r})\vec{E}(\vec{r})=0$$
Now let $\sigma$ **not a function of the place** ; that's mean $\sigma(\vec{r})=\sigma$ ;Then we have 
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}(\vec{r})=0 \tag{1}$$
And also we know that :
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}(\vec{r})=0 \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \text{Or} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \oint\vec{E}(\vec{r})\cdot d \vec{r}=0 \tag{2}$$

Now from the combination $(1),(2)$ ; We have

$$\nabla^2\varphi(\vec{r})=0 \tag{3}$$

Which $(3)$ is Laplace's equation . Equation of  $(3)$ is for  **an environment**  with **a conductivity** $(\sigma)$ that  **not a function of the place** . So why ? In **the Boundary Conditions** two environments with two conductivity ?

Comment: You can't do that, because of the product rule when taking the divergence of a scalar field multiplied by a vector field.

Comment: @BillyKalfus if $\sigma $ be a function of the place ; $\sigma(\vec{r})$
Then can we say that $\nabla ^2 \varphi(\vec{r})=0$ ?

Comment: The Laplace equation is just saying that you have a non-trivial electric field. Where is the scandal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, is it why does this condition only hold when $\sigma$ is not a function of position? Because in that case it is because if $\sigma$ DID depend on position then you would have $\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot(\sigma(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})) = \sigma(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}  + \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\sigma(\mathbf{r}) = 0$ instead. The second term in this expression can be neglected in the case where  $\sigma$ doesn't depend on position as then $\mathbf{\nabla}\sigma = 0$